# How to wait for onMapReady to do all the processing before the onActivityResult is called in android activity?

Tags: android

I'm trying to call `startActivityForResult()` and do the processing in the `onActivityResult()`. I've also implemented `onMapReady()` callback, which is initalizing variables and states of the activity and doing some processing. The problem is I can't access variable (getting nullpointerexception) which will be used for some processing in the `onActivityResult()`, because the `onActivityResult()` is called before the `onMapReady()` finished (it's async). I want to know how to wait for the `onMapReady()` finish before accessing `onActivityResult()`.

I've looked into this solution, but I can't call `onActivityResult()` manually.
[How to pause at an Android lifecycle stage until callback is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681064/how-to-pause-at-an-android-lifecycle-stage-until-callback-is-called)

Is there anyway I can hook the lifecycle events and start onActivityResult() after the onMapReady()?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use global variables?

see this for example:

```kotlin
var isMapReady = false
var onActivityResultCalled = false
fun doProcesses(){
    
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (isMapReady.not()) {
        onActivityResultCalled = true
    } else {
        doProcesses()
        onActivityResultCalled = false
    }
    
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    isMapReady = true
    if (onActivityResultCalled) doProcesses()
}
```

Comment: There are alot of processing and function running in the onActivityResult(). I can declare every variable as global, but that would hotch-potch my code. I am looking for a cleaner solution

Comment: @S.Joshi you can use `Flow` as a messaging queue between a coroutine `onActivityResult` and a coroutine `onMapReady`.